# Can someone tell me how i create table with current date(DD/MM/YYYY) as one column in table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want only date in one column not the current_timestamp.

```
create table attendence(date curdate);
create table attendence(date curdate());
create table attendence(date date); '
```

I used this but there was error

Comment: In hibernate there is a annotation called @temporal.DATE    && @ .TIME for date and time respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, MySQL does not give you this functionality.  As explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html), it does allow you to assign default values to `datetime` or `timestamp` columns.

If you need this functionality, you essentially have three options:

1. Use a trigger to assign the value.
2. Assign the value explicitly when inserting/updating rows.
3. Wrap the insert in a stored procedure and use that to set the value.

I guess there is also a fourth alternative, use a view.  Create a default datetime column and then access the table through a view:

```
create table v_t as
    select . . . , date(createdAt) as createdAt_date
    from t;
```

The following might works in the most recent releases:

```
create table t (
    i int,
    dt datetime default current_timestamp,
    d date as (date(dt))
);
```

That is, create a generated column off of the a default datetime.  Here is an [example](http://rextester.com/DQY11829).